# Имеет ли смысл делать отрисовку в потоке?

Tags: многопоточность, графика, graphics

Доброго времени суток!

Занимаюсь разработкой контрола в системе. Этот контрол представляет из себя что то вроде схем "ms visio". Не давно узнал, что некоторые используют для отрисовки отдельный поток. В принципе сама отрисовка в потоке вопросов у меня не вызывает, но синхронизация действий пользователя(выделение блоков, удаление блоков, редактирование, изменение состояний и тд) мне кажется довольно громоздким занятием для таких схем.

Под громоздким я понимаю, что в схеме довольно много различных объектов и состояний которые должны потоко-безопасно изменяться и при этом все должно быть плавно без тормозов.

Вопрос: Имеет ли смысл выносить отрисовку в отдельный поток для таких схем как в ms visio и если имеет, то какие основные принципы синхронизации в такой архитектуре?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вопрос не упоминает никакой конкретный фреймворк, предопределённого поведения нет. Некоторые фреймворки сами осуществляют за вас отрисовку в бэкграунде, некоторые рисуют синхронно.

Если вы хотите самостоятельно производить отрисовку в фоновом потоке, я бы делал так:

1. Код, работающий с UI-компонентами, имеет иллюзию однопоточности. То есть никакие блокировки не нужны.
2. При изменениях контролы должны отослать нотификацию в поток, занимающийся отрисовкой. Нотификация должна содержать все данные, необходимые для отрисовки, чтобы рисующий поток не должен был обращаться к главному потоку за информацией

При этом состояние UI будет немного отставать от «истинного» положения дел, но при достаточной скорости отрисовки это будет незаметно.

---

По поводу того, есть ли смысл так делать — вам придётся поэкспериментировать. К сожалению, очень сложно сказать заранее, какой будет эффект той или иной техники, и не проще ли просто докупить оборудование (хорошую графическую карту) и воспользоваться её возможностями. Напишите два прототипа и прогоните их на типичных для вашей программы задачах.

Comment: По поводу пункта 2: Я правильно понимаю, что при таком взаимодействии необходимо, чтобы у второго потока была его копия объектов и состояний?

Comment: @Vasek: Не обязательно. Можно отдавать не полную копию объекта, а лишь информацию, необходимую для отрисовки. Причём второй поток по идее может эту информацию и не кэшировать: определение точной области перерисовки можно сделать и в основном потоке, а для другого остальные объекты вроде бы и не нужны.

Comment: А если нужно перерисовать всю сцену? например при скроле.

Comment: Возможно, тогда имеет смысл скроллирующему коду не дать элементам списка отправлять нотификации, а отправить самому одну, кумулятивную нотификацию?

Comment: разобрался, спасибо